# Java Swing. Windows in front launched from JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe

The thing I want to implement is the next UI hierarchy in my Swing application.

1. Main Window (JFrame)
2. Modal dialog (JDialog) in front of this window. It's opened by clicking on the button in main window.
3. The set of windows in front of modal dialog (2). They should be independent from each other and non-blocking for modal jdialog (2).

How can I code this?

Comment: really i'm kinda new to stackoverflow, it's not the thing i've done special. :-) i'll try to fix it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the owner when you create the JDialogs. Read the JDialog API for the proper constructor to use. I would guse the owner of the dialog in point 3 would be the dialog in point 2.

Comment: And how can i set the dialog in pt 2 as an owner for dialogs in pt 3? I see that JDialog gets JFrame as an owner, not JDialog.

Comment: JDialog takes Dialog, Frame or Window as an owner. That should be enough